# Regex find variables with brackets without [' ']

Tags: php, regex, undefined, constants

Im tryning to upgrade from php 5.6 to php 7.2. But i got a lot of "Warning: Use of undefined constant" error messages.

The problem is that i have used e.g. $variable[name] all over the site.
But i need to be $variable['name'].

I tried to use a regex but problem is that matches stuff i dont want to match.

I got a half way solution:

```
\[([a-zA-Z-_\s]+)\]
```

Replaced with:

```
['$1']
```

e.g. i dont want to match [test] but want to match $variable[test]
e.g. dont want to match [1] (numbers int) but want to match [1_2] (combination with text and number)

Anyone who has any suggestions for a solution?

Comment: Apply rules more strictly `\$[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*\[\K([^'"\]]+)\]` then replace with `'$1']`. Check demo https://regex101.com/r/WLRw1d/1

Comment: How many lines of code are we talking about?

Comment: The main problem is: what if your code contains constants? I think the  only good way to update an old code (designed for a previous version) is the hard way: rewrite it.

Answer (score 2):

According to [PHP basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

> A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by
>   any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular
>   expression, it would be expressed thus:
>   `[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*`

Using this along with `\K` (match resetter, not a must) you can do this:

```
\$[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*\[\K([^]'"]+)\]
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Last part break down:

- `\K` Reset match
- `(` Start of capturing group #1

  - `[^]'"]+` Ensure quotation marks don't appear, match up to closing bracket
- `)` End of CG #1
- `]` Match closing bracket

Then replace with:

```
'$1']
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/WLRw1d/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You need [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/6JKYsS/2)?

```
/\$[a-z0-9_]+\[(.*?)\]/gi
```

With this you can match any `$variable[name]` and use `$1` to get value.

> **NOTE:** Be careful, because you can have inside `[]` variable, object or integer. You must made additional check of matched type for the
>   `name`.

Another good solution can be matching only string names.

```
/\$[a-z0-9_]+\[([a-z0-9\-\_\.]+)\]/gi
```

With this you can get exact what you need. [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/6JKYsS/4/)